# Delete multiple rows in Free-jqGrid with local grid (4.15)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I see many reference implementations here for achieving the ability to delete more than 1 selected rows in jqGrid.

However, all these implementation eventually do an iteration over a list of row ids and call delRowData in each of them.

when one is selecting say 1000 rows, this is not scaling well, as it seems we are waiting o(n) for every row deletion, resulting on o(n^2) for the entire operation.

is there a way to delete ALL selected rows with one single o(n)?

(One post I read was to send it over to the server and simply reload the all thing from scratch, as the overall saving in time is dramatically high.  I'm looking for a built in method within the jqGrid itself)

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: Which **datatype** you use? do you use simple grid, TreeGrid or some other kind of grid? Do you use local or remote paging? Which page size you use typically?

Comment: Thanks Oleg,  this is a simple grid, were all operations are made local (nothing is remote). The data size in this particular scenario is 10000 rows. User set the page size to 1000, “select all” and delete (so he want to delete all 1000 entries) without any filter or sorting applied. Removing all 1000 rows takes 20 seconds to complete using delRowData (in an iteration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start with common remark. It's not recommended to display more rows on the page as it will be possible to display at once. The performance of the grid with, for example, 10000 rows and 25 rows per page is essential better comparing with the usage 1000 row per page.

In any way, common changing of *multiple rows* of data in the local grid is not usage `delRowData` or `addRowData`. It's much more effective to **replace** the whole data. Typical code will be

```
var grid = $("#grid"),
    p = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"); // get reference to all parameters

p.data = newdata; // replace data parameter
grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

So I'd suggest you to get the copy of the data (or you have the data outside the grid already), remove the items with the ids, which need be removed, set new value of `p.data` and trigger `reloadGrid` to display the first page of modified data.

By the way, usage of `delRowData` is much slowly as you described. The reason is [web browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow). If you have the page with for example 1000x10 elements and you delete only the first row (you change 10 elements), then web browser have to recalculate css styles (for example position) of practically **all** existing elements on the page. Then deleting of the second row would be almost exactly so complex. Thus, the usage of `delRowData` or `addRowData` in the loop would be very ineffective. During reloading the grid jqGrid build **the whole** grid body as one HTML fragment and place it on DOM of the page in *one* operation. Because of that reloading of the grid could be very quickly.